# Gated creation of entities (Users etc) depending on existing count in the database MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, custom-action-filter

I have an application where an Administrator can create new users. New users can only be created if existing user count is less than what is allowed to the administrator (value set in the database in the account table)

Now i can easily just create an action filter checking the existing users count and depending on it, return an HttPStatusCodeResult for Bad request, or UnAuthorizedResult.

But what i want is that the "Create Button" should be disabled too. The create button is on the Index view. I can also do this by creating a custom html helper that renders the button as disabled depending on the count of existing users from the database.

But further on, I have other Entity Creation that needs to be gated depending on the count of existing entities in the database.

I would want to figure out a standard way of doing this accross the application, rather than create a seperate ActionLink helper and a seperate ActionFilter for each requirement.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you are saying that each administrator has say 5 users they can create, and after they create 5 the creation should be disabled to them?

Comment: Hi, yes, that's what I mean. And this is not only with Users. There are other entities that follow same flow.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is setup a role for the ability to create users and remove it when they have created too many. Whenever they create a user, check to see if they meet the threshold, if they do, remove this privilege from their account. The code would be something like this...

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles="CanCreateUsers")]
public ActionResult CreateUser(User u){
    var currentUser = GetCurrentUser(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if(currentUser.UsersCreated >= 5){
        UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(currentUser.UserID, "CanCreateUsers");
        //Probably want to refresh their cookies to refresh their roles too
    }

    UserManager.CreateAsync(u);
}
```

Then checking to see if a user can create users is as simple as checking their role

```
@if(User.IsInRole("CanCreateUsers"))
{
    <a>Create User</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method sounds too cumbersome. Imagine if the admin removes a user, then if the role "CanCreateUsers" is not present, then we first add it, then do the whole process of adding entity, then if the limit reaches, then we remove this role again. And we do that on every User add and remove. Its too much overhead and invitation to bugs

Comment: I think you are confused. Users should have roles anyway, if you remove a user you have to clear their roles. There's no problem here. When user's are added, they should get a set of roles. You have to add those roles to the user so it isn't any more to add this role. CanCreateUsers should be a persistent role in the DB. All you're doing is performing lookup and assignment of this role to the user's roles.

Comment: No, that's not what your answer says. I agree users should have roles and they do. What you are talking about here is for the User who is creating users (ADMIN) to have conditional role, that would need to be managed on every user he creates or removes. ADMINS role CanCreateUsers will be dependant on how many users he has already created as per your solution. If a user was added HIS (added user's) roles should be added. If a user is deleted HIS (deleted user's), that doesn't necessarily mean the ROLE will be deleted too. Roles are not user specific, Users belong to a ROLE.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are thinking this is too cumbersome. When users are created or removed, you (possibly) update the admin's roles. Throughout the rest of the application you now know which admins still have this permission.